# Posterior of an Interval under Beta Distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, bayesian

Suppose you have a beta prior with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  You draw $n \geq 1$ points from a binomial distribution and observe $k > n/2$ successes.  Does your posterior probability in the interval $[1/2,1]$ increase?  Intuitively, I think ``yes'', but I am bad at evaluating integrals.  Since the beta family is conjugate to the binomial distribution, I believe that we can rephrase the question as follows.  If $k$ and $n$ are positive integers such that $1 \leq k \leq n$ and $k > (n-k)$, is the following true?

$$\frac{1}{B(\alpha, \beta)} \int_{1/2}^{1} x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}dx < \frac{1}{B(\alpha+k, \beta+(n-k))} \int_{1/2}^{1} x^{\alpha+k-1}(1-x)^{\beta+n-k-1}dx$$

where $B(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the beta-function.

More generally, for $r \in [1/2,1)$, if one observes $k$ many successes in $n$ trials and $k/n > r$, does it follow that one's posterior in the interval $[r,1]$ increases?

Comment: Suppose prior on Success probability is $p\sim\mathsf{Beta}(2,1)$ so that $[.5,1]$ has prob. $0.75.$ Then if you get $k=7$ Successes in $n=10$ trials. Use Bayes' Thm. to multiply prior density by binomial likelihood to get posterior density proportional to $p^{2+7-1}(1-p)^{1+3-1},$ which is kernel of $\mathsf{Beta}(9,4),$ with prob.  $0.927002$ in $[.5,1].$ R code for probabilities: `1 - pbeta(.5, 2, 1)` returns $0.75$ and `1 - pbeta(.5, 9, 4)` returns $0.927002 > 0.75,$ as you supposed. In R, `pbeta` is a Beta CDF.

Comment: Finding the posterior is simple in this case because beta prior is _conjugate_ to binomial likelihood; i.e. of similar mathematical form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - suppose that your prior made you confident that $p$ was large. For example, suppose that $\alpha = 10, \beta = 1$. Then, if you saw 5 successes out of 9 trials, you would actually be less confident that $p$ was so large, and your posterior probability that $p > 1/2$ would be less than your prior probability that $p > 1/2$. (These choices of $\alpha, \beta, k, n$ were just a guess I made that happened to work.)

Letting $\alpha = 10, \beta = 1, k = 5, n = 9$, we have
$$\frac{1}{B(\alpha, \beta)} \int_{1/2}^{1} x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}dx = \frac{1}{B(10, 1)} \int_{1/2}^{1} x^{10-1}(1-x)^{1-1}dx = 0.9990234,$$
and
$$\frac{1}{B(\alpha+k, \beta+(n-k))} \int_{1/2}^{1} x^{\alpha+k-1}(1-x)^{\beta+n-k-1}dx = \frac{1}{B(15, 5)} \int_{1/2}^{1} x^{15-1}(1-x)^{5-1}dx = 0.9903946.$$
So the left-hand side of your formula is greater than the right-hand side in this case.

Comment: If you chose $k$ such that $k/n > \alpha / (\alpha + \beta)$ then the mean of the posterior distribution would be greater than the mean of the prior distribution for sure and I would guess that the posterior probability that $p > 1/2$ would be greater than the prior probability that $p > 1/2$.

Comment: I meant to ask the question you said “I guess that..” but you answered the question as written.  Any ideas for the harder question that can’t obviously be solved numerically?

Comment: OK I've got it. Let's set $\alpha/(\alpha+\beta) < 1/2$ but with $\alpha, \beta$ small so there's a lot of variance. And then set $k, n$ quite large but with $k/n < 1/2$ so that, once we've seen the data, we're certain that $p < 1/2$. For $\alpha = 1, \beta = 2$ we have the prior probability that $p > 1/2$ is $0.25$. If we let $k = 11, n = 30$ then the posterior probability that $p > 1/2$ is $0.055$ so there is a counter-example.

Comment: But for the previous comment I've dropped the $k/n>1/2$ constraint. If you keep that constraint then the hypothesis may be true.